# Magento: display default attribute filter on homepage / any page

Tags: xml, magento

I am looking for a way to display the default attribute filter on the homepage / any page.
I tried all kinds of settings in the backend (Category Manager and Attribute Manager), but the attribute filter never shows up on the home page. It neither shows up when the category is empty.

Could I do this with a Custom Layout Update in the "Category Manager" and/or the "CMS Manage Pages"? Do I need to make changes in the local.xml?

In case I need to work on the xml: could anybody get me on track?

Regards, Els

Answer (score 0):

Several options.
**First:** product specific by adding Custom Layout Update on any product page.
For instance:

```
<!-- LAYERED NAVIGATION in left column-->
<reference name="left">
<!-- Layered Navigation Block -->
    <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml">
    <block type="core/text_list" name="catalog.leftnav.state.renderers" as="state_renderers"/>
    </block>
</reference>
```

**Second:** use local.xml to trigger the layered navigation block appear on selected types of pages.

```
<!-- LAYERED NAVIGATION in left column-->
<default>
    <reference name="left">
    <!-- Layered Navigation Block -->
        <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml" >
        <block type="core/text_list" name="catalog.leftnav.state.renderers" as="state_renderers" />
        </block>
    </reference>
</default>
```